# Linux ssh (bug/broken) still working even when the service is stopped on linux ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd, bugs

Here is the whole scenario:

1. installed ssh apt-get install ssh
2. created a new user (I know I didn't have to)
3. logged into the system via ssh using the new user
4. modified the /etc/ssh/sshd_config to allow root login
5. issued the command systemctl status ssh
6. it showed that service was running
7. issued systemctl stop ssh (I know I could have used service cmd)
8. I was still logged in via ssh! not sure how that works
9. opened a new putty instance and tried to connect and it said service not accessible/timed out
10. issued systemctl start ssh and tried logging in as user with new putty instance and it worked

I was wondering why it didn't tear down the first instance (new user log-in via ssh)? was it because when I initially logged in, the ssh accepted the connection on port 22 and opened a new web socket port (multi-thread) and assigned my connection to that port and was listening to another connection on port 22 and when I logged in after stopping the service it said timed out?

I'm sure ssh doesn't keep track of the random port it opens, would you say it could possibly be a bug (not broken). Shouldn't the c program also keep track on ssh and also take down instances when ssh service has been stopped. any thoughts?

Comment: Worth noting is that step 7 was correct, you should use `systemctl` and not `service` if you're using a distro with `systemd`. If you use the `service` command on a `systemd` distro it just calls `systemctl` and warns you: `service httpd status: Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status httpd.service`

Comment: Such an obvious bug in such an old project would have been squashed ages before you wrote this question.

Answer (score 8):

This is intentional. When you connect to a system using SSH, the daemon on the target system spawns a new `sshd` process, or even two (one running as `root`, the other as the target user). The SSH session is handled by this new process, not the original one. From the manpage:

> `sshd` listens for connections from clients.  It is normally started at boot from `/etc/init.d/ssh` (or
>        `/etc/init/ssh.conf` on systems using the Upstart init daemon).  It forks a new daemon for each incoming connection.
>        The forked daemons handle key exchange, encryption, authentication, command execution, and data exchange.

When you stop the service, only the main daemon stops; the daemons which are managing sessions keep running. This is what enables you to restart the SSH server without losing your sessions — this is particularly handy when you get the configuration wrong and the server doesn't restart...

Comment: thanks! i was wondering if this was intentional or a bug.
many thanks!